# Problema consulta JPQL

Tags: java, jpa

Lo que necesito hacer es listar los proveedores que han respondido a un solo pedido. Hago la consulta pero me sale el error (Object comparisons can only be used with OneToOneMappings.  Other mapping comparisons must be done through query keys or direct attribute level comparisons)

La consulta que estoy haciendo es asi

SELECT e.cedulaProveedor FROM Aporte e, Pedido f where e.idPedido=1

La entidad de aporte esta asi

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "idAporte")
private Integer idAporte;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "cantidadAportada")
private int cantidadAportada;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "precioAporte")
private int precioAporte;
@JoinColumn(name = "idPedido", referencedColumnName = "idPedido")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Pedido idPedido;
@JoinColumn(name = "idProducto", referencedColumnName = "codigoProducto")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Producto idProducto;
@JoinColumn(name = "cedulaProveedor", referencedColumnName = "cedulaProveedor")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Proveedor cedulaProveedor;
```

Se que el error es porque tengo una relación entre las tablas Aportes y Pedidos y se relacionan por medio de la columna "idPedido", por lo tanto no puedo enviar el 1, pero no se como enviar el objeto de pedido que tenga el id 1.

Si me pudieran ayudar lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes hacer un JOIN para esta consulta. La cláusula JOIN te traerá la unión de 2 tablas por medio de un campo en común. En este caso, `Aporte` y `Pedido` se relacionan por medio de `idPedido` en JPA (y que se mapea a `id_pedido` en la tabla por lo general).

Tu consulta quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT e.cedularProveedor FROM Aporte e JOIN e.idPedido p WHERE p.idPedido = :idPedido
```

Lo que se traduce a:

```
SELECT e.cedular_proveedor FROM aporte e INNER JOIN Pedido p ON e.id_pedido = p.id_pedido WHERE e.id_pedido = ?
```

De esta manera obtienes los aportes que corresponden a un pedido específico.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: De nada. Saludos.

Comment: ¿No sería mejor y más directo `SELECT e.cedularProveedor FROM Aporte e WHERE e.idPedido.idPedido = :idPedido`?

Comment: Claro que sí, en caso no se necesite la información del pedido.

Answer (score 0):

No muestras el código del objeto `Pedido`, pero parece que estás confundiendo el objeto en sí, con su id.

La query debería ser:

```
SELECT e.cedulaProveedor FROM Aporte e, Pedido f where e.idPedido.id =1
```

Creo que lo más lógico sería renombrar tu atributo:

```
private Pedido idPedido;
```

Por:

```
private Pedido pedido;
```

De esta manera, la query quedaría más coherente:

```
SELECT e.cedulaProveedor FROM Aporte e, Pedido f where e.pedido.id =1
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Esta consulta JPQL te muestra los proveedores han respondido a un solo pedido:

```
SELECT aporte.cedulaproveedor, count( distinct aporte.pedido.idpedido ) 
FROM Aporte aporte 
GROUP BY aporte.cedulaproveedor HAVING count( distinct aporte.pedido.idpedido ) = 1
```

Principalment, hay tres clausulas utiles:

- El GROUP BY: te permite agrupar los aportes por cada proveedor
- El count distinct: te permite saber cuantos pedidos han sido realizados por cada proveedor
- El HAVING: te permite especificar que la cantidad de pedidos por proveedor que buscas es 1

He probado la consulta con el plugin Hibernate Tools de Eclipse, muy practico!